# How to set CMake build configuration in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm using the CMake Tools extension in VSCode to build and run a C++ project on Windows.

Where do I set if the build configuration should be `Debug` or `Release`?

On `Build`, CMake Tools executes

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/work/foobar/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD
```

How do I get the extension to build with `--config Release`?

Comment: This appears you're using VSCode for your code IDE and build, *and* Visual Studio (version unspecified) for your compiler/linker toolchain. Is that correct ? Regardless, look in the bottom status bar of the VS code IDE, on/near the lower left corner. You should see a `CMake: [Debug]: Ready` mini-panel. Click that. The build configurations should pop up near the middle-top of the screen, and should include Debug, Release, RelMinSize, and RelWithDebInfo (more or less).

Comment: @WhozCraig, this is great! I didn't know about the mini-panel!
You should submit this comment as an answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The CMake Tools extension sets up a **lot** of goodies, including a status bar panel for configuring various aspects of your build(s). In the status line various panels provided by VSCode and extensions can be enabled/disabled. And example including the CMake Tools mini panels appears below:

[image]

Note: I am *not* running VS Code on a Windows machine; mine is MacOS, but the premise is the same.

Anyway, if you click on the portion that says `CMake: [Debug]: Ready` a select-variant list should open near the top of the IDE in the location you're probably familiar seeing the general Command Palette open. It will look like this:

[image]

It is here you can change your selection from one build configuration type to another.

You can also do this via the main command palette by doing the following:

1. Hit ctrl-shift-P (or cmd-shift-P on MacOS)
2. Type `CMake`. The list should filter to just CMake command options.
3. Scroll the list and choose `CMake: Select Variant`

The same aforementioned build variant options should present themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For information, the CMake Tools extension status bar is now hidden by default. To show the status bar as mentioned in the other comment, do the following:

1. Extensions (Ctrl+Shift+X)
2. CMake Tools > Extension Settings
3. Search for "Status bar visibility" > select "visible"

[image: CMake Tools status bar settings]

Et voilà ! The status bar should appear at the bottom.